# NullPointerException by testing a Service with mocked JPARepository

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit

I have a ServiceImp where the repository and objectmapper are injected.

When performing the tests I get a nullpointexception.

I believe the Mock is working because when I print the result Candidate createdOne = candidateRepository.save(c1) I get back c1.

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))

public class CandidateServiceImp implements CandidateService {

private final CandidateRepository candidateRepository;
private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

@Override
public List<CandidateDto> getAllCandidates() {
    List<Candidate> candidateList = candidateRepository.findAll();
    return candidateList.stream()
            .map(Candidate::convertEntityToDto)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

@Override
public String findCandidateByIdNormal(Long id) throws JsonProcessingException {
    Candidate foundCandidate = candidateRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new CandidateNotFoundException(id));
    return objectMapper.writerWithView(CandidateViews.Normal.class).writeValueAsString(foundCandidate.convertEntityToDto());
}

@Override
public String findCandidateByIdHr(Long id) throws JsonProcessingException {
    Candidate foundCandidate = candidateRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new CandidateNotFoundException(id));
    return objectMapper.writerWithView(CandidateViews.Hr.class).writeValueAsString(foundCandidate.convertEntityToDto());
}

@Override
public CandidateDto createCandidate(CandidateDto candidateToCreateDto) {
    Candidate candidateToCreate = candidateToCreateDto.convertDtoToEntity();
    Candidate createdCandidate = candidateRepository.save(candidateToCreate);
    return createdCandidate.convertEntityToDto();
}
```

And this ist my test:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class CandidateServiceTest {

@InjectMocks
CandidateServiceImp candidateServiceImp;

@Mock
CandidateRepository candidateRepository;

private CandidateDto c1Dto;
private CandidateDto c2Dto;
private List<CandidateDto> candidateDtoList;

private Candidate c1;
private Candidate c2;
private List<Candidate> candidateList;

@BeforeEach
void setUp() {

    c1Dto = new CandidateDto("Peter", "Parker", "pp@gmail.com", 3500L);
    c2Dto = new CandidateDto("Mary", "Jane", "mj@gmail.com", 4500L);
    candidateDtoList = List.of(c1Dto, c2Dto);

    c1 = new Candidate("Peter", "Parker", "pp@gmail.com", 3500L);
    c2 = new Candidate("Mary", "Jane", "mj@gmail.com", 4500L);
    candidateList = List.of(c1, c2);
}

@Test
public void createCandidateShouldReturnCandidateDto() {
    Mockito.doReturn(c1).when(candidateRepository).save(c1);

    Candidate createdOne = candidateRepository.save(c1);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(createdOne.convertEntityToDto());
    System.out.println();

    assertEquals(c1Dto, candidateServiceImp.createCandidate(c1Dto));
}
```

And this is the message :

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "de.evoila.personalAbteilung.models.Candidate.convertEntityToDto()" because "createdCandidate" is null

Could someone tell me why it is not finding the createdCandidate?Thanks =D

Comment: Hi! Has `Candidate`  `@EqualsAndHashcode`? (mockito must "recognize" `c1` from "all possible objects"..)

Comment: @xerx593, Thanks, when I add `@EqualsAndHashcode` to Candidate works. =D
Candidate is also a `@Entity`, is it a problem to add `@EqualsAndHashCode` to an entity?

Comment: make it `@EqualsAndHashCode(of="id")` (more efficient, otherwise compares "all fields";)

Comment: no, not a problem! it is "best practise"!! :)

Comment: @vbiquin consider adding the solution as an answer and accepting it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the comments, one solution would be to add @EqualsAndHashCode to candidate.
I also find other solution :

```
@Test
public void createCandidateShouldReturnCandidateDto() {
    Mockito.when(candidateRepository.save(any(Candidate.class))).thenAnswer(AdditionalAnswers.returnsFirstArg());

    assertEquals(c1Dto, candidateServiceImp.createCandidate(c1Dto));
}
```

I mocked the repository with any(Candidate.class) and it also works.